# Servo motor speed control with PIC

Tags: pic, servo

I am controlling a servo motor using the PIC12F675. The servo rotates in opposite directions.

I controlling the servo as follows:

> 

```
if(GPIO & (1<<3))
        {
                GPIO |=(1<<2);
            __delay_ms(1);
            GPIO &=~(1<<2);

            }
            else
        {
                GPIO |=(1<<2);
            __delay_ms(2);
            GPIO &=~(1<<2);


            }

            __delay_ms(18);
```

I would like to control the rate at which the servo reaches the opposite ends. I tried looking for articles related to speed control, I found it to be too complicated to control the rate of sweep. I am looking for suggestions for the same

Comment: ...and what are GPIO bits 1 and 2?

Comment: @Jason I am sorry. GPIO 2 is the output at which the servo is operated. GPIO 3 has a toggle switch. I am planning to use a potentiometer for speed control

Comment: (right, I meant 2 and 3) -- We still have no idea what GPIO2 is supposed to do. You're creating a pulse... what does that do?

Comment: @JasonS I believe GPIO2 is supposed to simulate a PWM signal, in order to control the servo

Comment: @JasonS Yes I am creating a software PWM for the servo motor

Comment: which does what to the servo motor? PWM pulses = ??? Speed? Torque? Current? Voltage? Position?

Comment: @JasonS PWM pulses are signal to the servo. The servo is powered externally.

Comment: Again: How does the PWM pulse control the servo?

Comment: @JasonS According to my understanding, the ON time in the servo determines the angle to which the servo should turn. The total time cycle is approximately 20ms and setting the servo at 0.9ms turns it to one end, 1.5ms of ON time turns it to the center, and 2.1 ms to the opposite end

Comment: @JasonS What Sai's trying to do is: every time the input pin GPIO3 (button?) goes high, the output pin GPIO2 goes high for 1 ms, positioning the servo at -90 degrees; conversely, when the input pin goes low (button released?), the output pin GPIO2 goes high for 2 ms, positioning the servo at +90 degrees. The it waits for another 18 ms, because a servo needs to update it's position every 20 ms

Comment: There is very confusing terminology being used here. Is this(1)  a "servomotor" or "servo motor"  which is a high performance rotating motor with speed feedback OR (2) a radio control type "servo" which is a geared motor that is intended to provide position control over a range of 90 to 180 degrees. || From what is being said I understand it to be the latter

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Servos work by listening for 20ms, then adjusting the position based on the duration of the high pulse.

The high pulse (`X` below) can be between 1ms and 2ms long, with 1.5ms as the neutral or centre position.

```
 |------------20ms-----------|
 |-X-|                
  ___                         ___
_|   |_______________________|   |___ ...
```

Depending on your servo, -90° (left of centre) is usually ~1ms, 90° (right of centre) is ~2ms.

If it's at 0° and you send it a 1ms signal, it will try to turn to it's -90° position as fast as it can. The maximum speed varies from servo to servo (data sheets often specify a 0-60° time), and also depends on the voltage you give it (Hitec HS-422 at 4.8V takes 0.21 sec, at 6V takes 0.16 sec).

If you want to vary the speed (not just as fast as it can), you need to tell it to change it's position gradually.

You can do this by sending a series of position signals (each 20ms long with an `X` ms high pulse).

If we send 50 pulses, slowly from 1.5ms to 1ms stepping down 0.01ms each time, X will equal:

```
1.50ms, 1.49ms, 1.48ms, ... , 1.02ms, 1.01ms, 1.00ms
```

then, assuming that it can turn as rapidly as we want it to, it'll take `50 (number of 20ms signals) x 20 ms (length of pulse) = 1s` to get from 0° to -90°.

---

Send a 20ms pulse with x ms high: (psudocode)

```
function send_signal (x):
    set output high
    wait x ms
    set output low
    wait (20 - x) ms
```

Make a servo slowly pan from left (-90°) to right (90°)

Psudocode:

```
loop x from 1 to 2, step 0.01
    send_signal(x)
```

Or if you prefer, in C (99):

```
for (float x = 1; x <= 2; x += 0.01) {
    send_signal(x);
}
```

Comment: Pretty nice answer!

Comment: Thanks! I thought it might be useful to cover the basics since Jason's answer was quite technical

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you generalize your system to something like the following:

```
int T = 200   // 200*100usec = 20msec period
while(1)
{
   u = compute_next_duty_cycle()
   servo_output_on();
   __delay_100us(u)       
   servo_output_off();
   __delay_100us(T-u)
}
```

where `servo_output_xxxx()` turns the GPIO on and off. You're almost certainly going to have to improve the granularity of your delays, if you choose to use a software PWM; 1msec delay steps only give you 5% increments in PWM duty cycle for a 20msec loop.

You'll have to ramp `u` up and down; a fixed slew rate should suffice (more complicated trajectory control would limit acceleration as well):

```
 pseudocode for ramping u given a position goal ufinal and max slewrate v:

 delta = ufinal - u;
 delta = min(v, max(-v, delta));   // limit delta to +/- v
 u += delta
```

If you need a very slow ramp, you'll have to internally use a high-resolution state for u, and then divide/shift to get your output command:

```
 delta = ufinal - u;
 delta = min(v, max(-v, delta));   // limit delta to +/- v
 u += delta
 uout = u >> 8;  // or >> 16 or whatever
 servo_output_on();
 __delay_100us(uout)       
 servo_output_off();
 __delay_100us(T-uout)
```